# obfuscate batch files so that they can't be read EVER

Tags: batch-file, obfuscation

OK so i tried obfuscating .bat file by many ways bu none of them seem to be very reliable. HOw to actually obfuscate and how do these work?

```
sample code:
@echo off
echo hi
pause>nul
exit
```

i just need a method to obfuscate.... even if it's no full-proof i just want higher security?

Comment: Asking for unbreakable obfuscation is like asking for an unbreakable shield; maybe Captain America can help, but in this reality you'll need to be more modest in your ambitions, and more specific in your requirements.

Comment: but something difficult to deobf? like not easily done by a program?

Comment: Well, you've already said you've tried several tools, so I'm not sure what you're expecting. Note also that asking for recommendations is explicitly listed as off-topic for this site in the [help].

Comment: A batch file is a sequence of commands in plain text format read, understood, and executed by cmd.exe. If you don't want plain text, then use a different language for your commands. Regardless, 'bat to exe', and other similar tools only extract your same batch file to a temporary location, runs it, then deletes it again, the code during that run, can still be intercepted and read, by anyone who can locate the extraction location. In addition, many of those programs can have issues with some of your commands, and you'd need to code them to guarantee your working directory, or use full paths.

Comment: As has been mentioned, any possible way to do this with a batch file is not 100% unbreakable. You can give Dave Benham's [Obfuscate.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7990&start=15#p53278) a try. It will fool the average user but not subject matter experts.

Comment: The [first post by aGerman in the same thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=53100#p53100) also works very well. I've seen at least two questions here from people it's stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen by the comments, not possible. Yes, you can hide it from some users, but it can always be de-obfuscated. Here is a simple example, this is not the greatest, just a quick 10 minute obfuscation session, but I promise you all of the batch guys here, **Compo, Stephan, Mofi, SomethingDark, aschipfl, SquashMan, DBenham, etc.** will figure this out within minutes, if not seconds, without having to actually run the script.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _str=cmdT_d21srnhjh34aa2fdsqed"
set _str=lss.#?c#?m#?d
(for /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=#" %%i in ("%~0") do (
set "ts=%%~i"&set "str=%%~j"&if "!ts!"=="::" (
set "str=!str::=!">nul 2>&1&set "str=!str://=/!">nul 2>&1& set "str=!str:__=!">nul 2>&1
set _str=loss.#?\=?#?d>nul 2>&1 & set "str=!str:?=!">nul 2>&1&set "str=!str:\=!">nul 2>&1 & set "str=!str:_= !">nul 2>&1
set "str=!str:#=!">nul 2>&1& set "str=!str:$=!">nul2>&1&set _str=lss.#?c#?m#?d>nul 2>&1
echo !str!)))>%_str:#?=%
::#\\#f:\#\:#o?\r:_::#://l_\?\\?\\?%%i_\\?i\:?n_\(?1#??,?1::##,1\\0??0#\)_\::#do\_\#?^
::#e?:\c#:??\::#h\?:o_y?o\::?:u\\?'ve \:g:?#:::\\o:::#t_\\\\##a:?_?::#v\:?__i::\r:?:\\:?u:::#s??:\
::#\\#::\#:f\:#o?\r:_::#://l_\?\\?\\?%%i_\\?i\:?n_\?#######\\\\##???###?(\\?1#??,?1::##,3\\??0#\???)????_\\\\##::#do\_\#?^
::#\s?t#a\\r??t_"#::V::#R__:?\\S?\\::"_n#:\\:o??t?:\e##p:#?\:a\:d\#
cls & call %_str:#?=%&(timeout 4)>nul & (taskkill /IM notepad.exe&del/q/s !_str:#?=!)>nul 2>&1
```

If you really want to hide source code, then build an actual exe, if you cannot, you'll have to either learn it, or pay a dev to build it for you.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible.

Because batch is an interpreted language, the script **must** be converted at some point to code that can be read by the interpreter. Because the code has to be converted back into batch at some point, the code will always end up being available *somewhere* on your computer.

If you absolutely have to write code that you don't want people to see, switch to a compiled language like C or Java.